# why local remote host gives HTTP Error 404?

Tags: php, http, nginx

we have a website save into my boss computer using nginx server. I set my boss Ip into my host file like this [192.168.15.100 web.local.com]. Last few days ago I can accessed it. But now I cant access. It gives HTTP ERROR 404. Page not found. What could be the solution for this or how can I fix the problem? Thank you :)

Comment: Is the service running on his machine?

Comment: @SuitBoyApps If the service weren't running, how could it return an HTTP error code?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Serverfault.com might also be a good place to ask about configuring nginx.

Comment: Yes the server is running on his machine.

Comment: have you tried accessing directly -via- IP address?  How about locally

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix no its not working. same problem it gives http error 404

Comment: Did you set your machine's IP to be static?

Comment: @sheeks06 no DHCP all IP connected to internet router

Comment: did you check the nginx logs? it will help the community if you post logs, folder structure, etc. to compliment your problem. there are a lot of situation that can contribute to this issue.

Comment: Have you tried it locally from the machine it is on?  See it's between it not running at all, or some network routing issue.  This would rule out it just not up and running.

Comment: What are you guys all talking about with all these network connectivity questions?! 404 is "not found". That means the browser successfully connected to the server, and it responded by saying "I don't have that file". His boss probably deleted the file in question.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart no, files doesnt deleted. when I run on my localhost I can access the site, but I need to connect to my boss server because it is faster.

Comment: @sheeks06 I checked the log but it dont contains log from todays date

Answer (score 0):

In a network "local or not", the ip are given  by default dynamically. you must entered in the livebox (192.168.1.1, most of the time), and set the server IP to fixed.

as for the log in the livebox, it is sometimes written on his back.

Comment: livebox? we dont use that thing

Comment: you have an router ?

Comment: Yes we have a router